Errors after upgrading to 24.04: time out waiting for device, dependency failed, transaction for graphical.target is destructive
Yesterday I got the message that upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04.1 was available (I am on 22.04). In the middle of the upgrading process, the system warned that the internet connection was not available and interrupted the process (informing that the system would be reset to the original state, or something like that).
It seemed that everything was ok, but some icons were missing. I tried to reboot and the system was not able to boot anymore.
I get the following messages:
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/XXXX-XXXX (this is sda1, where I suppose /boot/efi should be mounted)
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /boot/efi
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Local File Systems
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/XXXX-XXXX
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/YYYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYYYY (this is nvme0n1p1, where /home should be mounted)
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Cryptography Setup for nvme0n1p1_crypt
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Local Encrypted Volumes
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /dev/mapper/nvme0n1p1_crypt
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Local File Systems /dev/mapper/nvme0n1p1_crypt
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /home
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/ZZZZZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZZZZZZ (this is sda8, where system is installed)
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Cryptography Setup for sda8_crypt
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/KKKKKKKKK-KKKK-KKKK-KKKK-KKKKKKKKKK (this is sda7, where /boot should be mounted)
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /boot
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Unattended Upgrades Shutdown
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/KKKKKKKKK-KKKK-KKKK-KKKK-KKKKKKKKKK

Then the system seems to enter into emergency mode (or something like that), with the following messages:
emergency.service
console-setup.service
[FAILED] Failed to start Set Up Additional Binary Formats
ufw.service
systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
systemd-update-utmp.service
apparmor.service
systemd-oomd.service
systemd-resolved.service
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit" to boot into default mode.

Press Enter for maintenance mode (or press ctrl+D to continue)

(sorry for any typos, I had to type all those messages...)
Additional information:
I have a LG Gram with dual boot (Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 10).
I have two disks. The original disk which came with the computer, where Windows and Ubuntu are installed, and a second internal disk, where my /home folder is installed.
I have already read lots of forums with people with similar problems (for instance: here, here, and here, and many others since yesterday) but couldn't find a solution.
If I use fsck I only get message from sda7 ("clean"); when I try in other devices (sda8, nvme0n1p1 etc) nothing happens (no error messages, but also no "clean" message).
I have also tried to boot into recovery mode and use older kernels. The result is always the same.
I have also tried boot-repair. Did not help.
In maintenance mode I don't have internet access, otherwise I could try again to upgrade the system.
If I press ctrl+D, I get the message:
Failed to start default target: Transaction for graphical.target/start is destructive (emergency.target has 'start' job queued, but 'stop' is included in transaction)

I have booted with Live CD and I can confirm that all disks and partitions seem to be perfectly fine (I can mount them, even the encrypted ones, I can read the files and copy them).
My last chance is of course reinstall the whole system. But I would like to wait if someone is able to help me.
Thanks a lot!

Install a fresh copy of the OS and restore your data from the backup you made before starting the upgrade.
